# How to load a flat file(not delimited file) into HBase?

Tags: hadoop, load, hbase, flat-file, biginsights

I am new to hbase and I have a flat file(not delimited file) that I would like to load into a single hbase table.

Here is a preview of a row in my file:

> 0107E07201512310015071C11100747012015123100

I know fo example that from position 1 to 7 it's an id and from position 7 to 15 it's a date....

The problem is how to build a schema that correspond to my file or if there is a way to convert it to a delimited file or read such file using jaql because I'm working with Infosphere BigInsights.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Hive table using RegExSerDe

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE testtable ((col1 STRING, col2 STRING, col3 STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe’
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (“input.regex” = “(.{5})(.{6})(.{3}).*” )
LOCATION ‘<hdfs-file-location>’;
```

You can create hive table pointing to HBase 
Here are the instructions 
http://hortonworks.com/blog/hbase-via-hive-part-1/

You can use 
insert overwrite table to load the data from hive table to HBase-table 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-SELECTSandFILTERS

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `SerDe` to deserialize into Hive and use Hive to export to HBase.