# How to load a flat file(not delimited file) into HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I am very new to hbase and I have a flat file(not delimited file) that I would like to load into a single hbase table.

Here is a preview of a row in my file:

> 0107E07201512310015071C11100747012015123100

I know fo example that from position 1 to 7 it's an id and from position 7 to 15 it's a date....

The problem is how to build a schema that correspond to my file or if there is a way to convert it to a delimited file or read such file using jaql because I'm working with Infosphere BigInsights.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a flat file(not delimited file) into HBase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703803/how-to-load-a-flat-filenot-delimited-file-into-hbase)

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Hbase but this should help. http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/admin_hbase_import.html

btw. never try to know how its seperated in the file just separete it by \t or ; or | something thats clear.